# "Unknown BaseAggregationBuilder [significant_text]" in Elastic search 5.3.2 version

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elk

to achieve aggregation for text field i tried giving

```
"aggs": {
    "keywords": {
      "significant_text": {
        "field": "testId",
        "min_doc_count":1
        }
    }
}
```

this works fine in elk 6.6.1 version. but in ELK 5.3.1 version it throws an error

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "unknown_named_object_exception",
        "reason": "Unknown BaseAggregationBuilder [significant_text]",
        "line": 107,
        "col": 27
      }
    ],
    "type": "unknown_named_object_exception",
    "reason": "Unknown BaseAggregationBuilder [significant_text]",
    "line": 107,
    "col": 27`enter code here`
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

can anyone please help me in sorting this out ?

Answer (score 0):

[Significant text aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/search-aggregations-bucket-significanttext-aggregation.html) was introduced in the 6.0 elasticsearch version, due to this for ELK version 5.3.1, you are getting the below error

> "Unknown BaseAggregationBuilder [significant_text]",

Comment: i know that. Is there any way to achieve the same with aggregation without updating index.